# MySQL: Operations on different alias to generate a new one

Tags: mysql, alias

It is possible to calculate the **mnt_res** column based on other columns?

```
CREATE ALGORITHM=UNDEFINED SQL SECURITY DEFINER
 VIEW v_test AS 
SELECT 
  func_calculate_total(...) AS mnt_total
  func_calculate_one(...) AS mnt_one,
  func_calculate_two(...) AS mnt_two,
  (mnt_total - mnt_one - mnt_two) AS mnt_res     /* Problem */
FROM ...
```

There is a way to do this without calling functions again?
Or would you do that calculation with php for example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alas, this is not really possible in MySQL.  You can define it, but you need to call the two functions again.

MySQL does not allow you to use subqueries in the `from` clause.  If so, then this would be easy using a subquery.  It is the only database (to my knowledge) that has this restriction.

In general, SQL does not allow you to refer to a column alias in the same `select` where it is defined.  So that is also not possible.

One way that you can get this done is using two views:

```
CREATE VIEW _v_test AS 
    SELECT 
      func_calculate_total(...) AS mnt_total
      func_calculate_one(...) AS mnt_one,
      func_calculate_two(...) AS mnt_two
    FROM ...

CREATE VIEW v_test as
    SELECT vt.*, (mnt_total - mnt_one - mnt_two) AS mnt_res 
    FROM _v_test vt;
```